.NET MySqlDataReader MaxLength on GROUP_CONCAT on utf-8 columns always 341
I have a problem loading data from MySQL into a datatable.
The Table was created with
CREATE TABLE `new_table` (
   `TheKey` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `strColumn` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`TheKey`),
   UNIQUE KEY `PrimaryKey_UNIQUE` (`TheKey`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

and then filled with enough entries that their total length is above 341.
I try to load that tables content into a VB .NET datatable using the following code:
Dim dtbl As New System.Data.DataTable
Using sqlCMD As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand = conMySQLConnection.CreateCommand()
    sqlCMD.CommandText = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(strColumn SEPARATOR '; ') FROM new_table;"
    Using reader As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader = sqlCMD.ExecuteReader()
        dtbl.Load(reader) ' throws a System.Data.ConstraintException: Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.'

    End Using
End Using
print(dtbl.Columns(0).MaxLength) ' 341, Except in some cases with a more complex Join/Where query, where MaxLength was 3072.'
print(Cstr(dtbl.Rows(0).Item(0)).Length) ' 10124'
print(dtblReturn.GetErrors(0).RowError) ' Column 'GROUP_CONCAT(strColumn SEPARATOR '; ')' exceeds the MaxLength limit.

My current workaround is to change the columns Charset to latin1, where the MaxLength is correctly set to 1024, but this seems like a bug in System.Data.DataTable or MySqlDataReader.

Seems like a bug in ...  Very possible. Most people use MySql Connector/NET instead of MySql.Data, because the latter is kinda buggy.
